# Zend_Controller_Router_Route dynamic route

Tags: zend-framework

Assuming the following router:

```
$router->addRoute('listOfFacilities',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:lang/:type/',
                   array('module' => 'default',
                         'controller' => 'search',
                         'action' => 'index',
                         'lang' => 'de',
                         'type' => ':type'
                        )));
```

Result will be:
http://example/en/Hotels/

lang == en
type == Hotels

It's possible to do in such way that for only one language, for example the german, the result is http://example/Hotels/ and not http://example/de/Hotels/?

Tanks,

Answer (score 0):

From a route point of view, just ditch the lang parameter to just have the "type" one.

```
$router->addRoute('listOfFacilities',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:lang/:type/',
               array('module' => 'default',
                     'controller' => 'search',
                     'action' => 'index',
                     'lang' => 'de',
                     'type' => ':type'
                    )));
$router->addRoute('listOfFacilities_default',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:type',
               array('module' => 'default',
                     'controller' => 'search',
                     'action' => 'index',
                     'type' => ':type'
                    )));
```

And from a controller point of view, just look for an empty lang parameter to define the default one (in your case, de).

If your page is already redirecting to /de/Hotels, then in our controller test for this :

```
if($lang == 'de' && $type == 'Hotels') {
     $this->_redirect('/Hotels');
}
```